# De select para input

Tags: html, formulário, input

Como em um formulário com um campo `select` quando `option = outro` sempre mudaria para um `input`? Como fazer?

```
<form action="">
    <div id="alvo">
       <select name="opcoes" id="select">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="outro">outro</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Está difícil de entender. Vc quer que quando selecionar a opção "Outro" no Select ele se transforme em um Input text normal, é isso?

Answer (score 2):

Pode mostrar o `input` ao selecionar o `option = outro` e esconder o `select`

Junto com o `input` tem `botão cancelar` que oculta o `input` e volta a mostrar o `select`

```js
$(function() {
    $('#meuDiv').hide();

    $('#select').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === 'outro') {
            $('#meuDiv').show();
            $('#select').hide();
        }
    });

    $('#cancel').click(function () {
        $('#select').show();
        $('#select').val('');
        $('#meuDiv').hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
<div id="alvo">
<select name="opcoes" id="select">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="outro">outro</option>
</select>

 <div id="meuDiv">
     <input type="text"/>
     <button type="button" id="cancel">Cancelar</button>
 </div>

</div>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não consegue *transformar* um `select` em `input`. Em vez disso, insira um `input` tipo `hidden` após o `select`. Ao selecionar a opção `outro` no `select`, o script esconde o `select` e mostra o `input` no lugar, que herdará o mesmo `name` do `select`, e o `select` perde o `name` para não ter conflito ao enviar o formulário.

**Veja:**

```js
$("#select").change(function(){
   
   if($(this).val() == "outro"){
      $(this)
      .attr("name", "")
      .hide()
      .next("input").attr({
         "type": "text",
         "name": "opcoes"
      })
      .focus();
   }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
   <div id="alvo">
      <select name="opcoes" id="select">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="outro">outro</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" />
   </div>
</form>
```

### Reversão

Caso deseje que o `select` volte a aparecer, você pode incluir um pequeno botão <kbd>x</kbd> para reverter o processo.

Neste caso terá que inserir o `input` em um elemento. No caso, usei um `span`. Neste caso, o `input` *escondido* não precisa ser do tipo `hidden`, porque ele estará escondido pelo *span-pai*. Também é preciso alterar partes do código dado no primeiro exemplo (como seletores e capturar os tipos de eventos):

```js
$("#select, #alvo span button").on("change click", function(e){
   
   
   if($(this).val() == "outro" && e.type == "change"){

      $(this)
      .attr("name", "")
      .hide()
      .next("span")
      .show()
      .find("input")
      .attr("name", "opcoes")
      .focus();

   }else if(e.target.id != "select" && e.type == "click"){

      $("#select")
      .attr("name", "opcoes")
      .show()
      .val('')
      .next("span")
      .hide()
      .find("input")
      .attr("name", "")
      .val('');

   }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
   <div id="alvo">
      <select name="opcoes" id="select">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="outro">outro</option>
      </select>
      <span style="display: none;">
         <input type="text" />
         <button type="button">x</button>
      </span>
   </div>
</form>
```